# Selenium file download test case in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I downloaded a file in one of my local folder(say `CSV_downloads`) using selenium and its working fine,but when I am pushing same code to Git and running it in `jenkins`,though that folder(`CSV_downloads`) exists in `jenkins` workspace(`CSV_downloads`) its not downloading `csv` to that particular folder(`CSV_downloads`) in `jenkins`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a hard coded location like `C:\CSV_downloads` then it will not be downloaded into `jenkins` folder. So you have to see the folder locations in local and remote machines.

Try to use relative paths like `System.getProperty("user.dir") +"//folders.."` where `System.getProperty("user.dir")` is your project folder.

also if the folder is not there then try to create directory like `folderName.mkdirs();`